# html select xsl if statement breaking code

Tags: xml, xslt

Here's my XSL code:

```
<select class="toptype" id="toptype" onchange="toptype()">
    <option value="numcomments" <xsl:if test="/*/general/viewmethod='numcomments'">selected="true"</xsl:if>>Number of Comments</option>
    <option value="numreviews" <xsl:if test="/*/general/viewmethod='numreviews'">selected="true"</xsl:if>>>Number of Reviews</option>
    <option value="highestreviews" <xsl:if test="/*/general/viewmethod='highestreviews'">selected="true"</xsl:if>>>Highest Reviewal Value</option>
</select>
```

Here's my XML:

```
 <general><viewmethod>numcomments</viewmethod></general>
```

**It seems to break the page.**

UPDATE:

I tried using `<xsl:attribute>` as outlined by one of the answers. Still broke the page.

Here's my `XSL code`.

```
    <select class="toptype" id="toptype" onchange="toptype()">
        <option <xsl:if test="/*/general/viewmethod='numcomments'"><xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute></xsl:if> value="numcomments">Number of Comments</option>
        <option <xsl:if test="/*/general/viewmethod='numreviews'"><xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute></xsl:if> value="numreviews">Number of Reviews</option>
        <option <xsl:if test="/*/general/viewmethod='highestreviews'"><xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute></xsl:if> value="highestreviews">Highest Review Value</option>
        <option <xsl:if test="/*/general/viewmethod='numlikes'"><xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute></xsl:if> value="numlikes">Number of Likes</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: XML tags cannot be nested.

Comment: @michael.hor257k can you provide a working answer?

Comment: Sure. After you provide a reproducible example, and include the expected result - see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  e.g. `<option value="numcomments"><xsl:if test="/*/general/viewmethod='numcomments'"><xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>Number of comments </option>`.

Comment: You have not used what I suggested, make sure you follow the sample I posted which puts the `<xsl:if>` as a child of the `option` element.